# Неверное выполнение AsyncTask

Tags: android, java

Выполняю JSON запрос, с ним то все ок, ответ JSON приходит в правильной форме, но почему-то при выполнении SETTEXT у `TextView` возникает проблема, выполняется только первый и все, то есть только  `artist1.setText(res111+" - ");`, причем если поставлю, допустим, вначале `artist2`, а потом `artist1`, то выполнится `artist1`; то есть, как я понял, раньше чем надо закрывается  `protected File doInBackground(String... params)`. 
Что не так???

```
 private class DownloadVkList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, File> {
     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
         progressDialog.setTitle("Пожалуйста подождите");
          progressDialog.setMessage("Загружаю список аудиозаписей");
          progressDialog.setCancelable(false); 
          progressDialog.show();
          VkApi ();
        } 
     @Override
        protected File doInBackground(String... params) {   
         //InputStream input = null;
         int count1 = 9;
         try {
            array = api.getAudiomy(account.user_id, null, count1);
            obj1 = array.getJSONObject(0);
            obj2 = array.getJSONObject(1);
            obj3 = array.getJSONObject(2);
            obj4 = array.getJSONObject(3);
            obj5 = array.getJSONObject(4);
            obj6 = array.getJSONObject(5);
            obj7 = array.getJSONObject(6);
            obj8 = array.getJSONObject(7);
            obj9 = array.getJSONObject(8);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res1 = obj1.getString("url");
            res11 = obj1.getString("title");
            res111 = obj1.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res2 = obj2.getString("url");
            res22 = obj2.getString("title");
            res222 = obj2.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res3 = obj3.getString("url");
            res33 = obj3.getString("title");
            res333 = obj3.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res4 = obj4.getString("url");
            res44 = obj4.getString("title");
            res444 = obj4.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res5 = obj5.getString("url");
            res55 = obj5.getString("title");
            res555 = obj5.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res6 = obj6.getString("url");
            res66 = obj6.getString("title");
            res666 = obj6.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res7 = obj7.getString("url");
            res77 = obj7.getString("title");
            res777 = obj7.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res8 = obj8.getString("url");
            res88 = obj8.getString("title");
            res888 = obj8.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            res9 = obj9.getString("url");
            res99 = obj9.getString("title");
            res999 = obj9.getString("artist");
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
            while (artist9.getText() != "artist9") {                          
                artist1.setText(res111+" - ");
                artist2.setText(res222+" - ");
                artist3.setText(res333+" - ");
                artist4.setText(res444+" - ");
                artist5.setText(res555+" - ");
                artist6.setText(res666+" - ");
                artist7.setText(res777+" - ");
                artist8.setText(res888+" - ");
                artist9.setText(res999+" - ");
                song1.setText(res11);
            song2.setText(res22);
            song3.setText(res33);
            song4.setText(res44);
            song5.setText(res55);
            song6.setText(res66);
            song7.setText(res77);
            song8.setText(res88);
            song9.setText(res99);

            }
              //Показать сообщение в UI потоке 
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
         return null;
     }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
     }
```

Comment: аццкий код =)

Comment: За такой код надо убивать и не допускать до компа - ваще жесть. Особенно мне нравится `while (artist9.getText() != "artist9")` - в сочетании с `obj1...obj9` наводит на сомнения о разумности создателя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что не так???

Все не так. Попробую максимально взвешенно:

1. Зачем вам `obj1...obj9`, а если бы дорожек было бы миллион - написали бы видимо миллион строк кода? Аналогичный вопрос и по `songN` и `resXXX`
2. `while (artist9.getText() != "artist9")` - это конечно шыдевр

В общем вкурите учебник, подумайте внимательно и запомните что программирование это способ автоматизации однообразных вычислений.